# Receiving download popup when trying to access any PHP files using MAMP

Tags: php, apache, mamp, osx-elcapitan

I am trying to add an existing WordPress project to my local machine for testing.  I am using MAMP on a Mac El Capitan environment.  I am able to start MAMP and see two green lights for Apache server and MySQL server, I am able to restore the database to the MySQL instance.

I placed the WordPress folder in the htdocs folder.  If I click the my website link on the MAMP admin webpage, I receive an "index of /" page which displays all of the folders under the htdocs folder.  So far so good, until I click the folder containing my WordPress files or navigate to localhost/myproject and I receive the following download popup:

[image: Download Popup]

After browsing the internet looking for answers, I was pointed to look at the apache_error.log file where I see several entries for "client denied by server configuration: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/.DS_Store, referer: http://localhost/MAMP/?language=English" in the log file.  I checked the permission for the htdocs folder and it was set to 775. I am stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Seems PHP is not installed, or Apache is not configured to use it on PHP files.

Try this first, create an .htaccess file with the following text and put it in your htdocs folder.

```
 AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

If that doesn't work, I suggest downloading and re-installing PHP directly (not using MAMP)  I'm not a MAMP user but I've read numerous tales where it's PHP installer is broken.